# In Active Directory are Users always stored in the Users folder?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am in a position where I am working with some very basic AD authentication. Basically as long as I can bind with some credentials, I consider a user authenticated with AD and I'm done. The difficult thing is I don't have access to the AD server and know very little about AD in general. So I cannot answer my own simple question and my requirement is kind of odd.

I need to let a user manually log in (by typing a user name and password) to *a different* AD login via LDAP than they are currently logged in as in Windows through a Chrome browser. So they are "authenticated" via NTLM, but now they can log in as someone else. Yes, weird, but that's the requirement.

From the initial NTLM process between the browser and Node.js, I get the URL to the AD and I get 3/4 attributes that I *think* I need.
I get 3 `DC` attributes which match what I expect, but I don't get the `CN` which in my case is `CN=Users`. Basically it looks something like

`CN=Users,DC=ABC1,DC=ABC2,DC=ABC3`

But from the initial NTLM I *don't* get the `CN=Users` anywhere.

So to my question! In AD is the folder that contains users always called `Users`? Or am I a bit screwed since I cannot obtain that final `CN` value from the initial NTLM process. Maybe there is another NTLM message I can send to get more info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Users` is just a container. Users and other objects can be stored in Organizational Units (OUs). As [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc759186(v=ws.10)#active-directory-domains-and-forests-1) says:

> OUs provide a means for administrators to group resources, such as user accounts or computer accounts, so that the resources can be managed as one unit. This makes it much easier to apply Group Policy to multiple computers or to control the access of many users to a single resource. OUs also make it easier to delegate control over resources to various administrators.

The string you are talking about is [a Distinguished Name (DN)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names) (example: `CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM`)

However, I don't understand why do you want to retrieve the DN for the user while logging in? You should be able to log on with the UPN (User Principal Name), such as: `username@example.org`

Comment: It's weird but the flow is: 1. Authenticate via browser and Node.JS using NTLM (works). 2. Authenticate again with a manual username/password via LDAP, making use of any information obtained through the NTLM process. Using LDAP I need to provide an IP address and the DN.. AFAIK we don't have any `user@something` type names..

Comment: @tester778899 if it's Active Directory yes, you have `user@something` by default. Ask your Active Directory administrator for further information.

Comment: You are correct. So I have one username, `Admin`, that works properly when I do a bind request like `CN=Admin,CN=Users,DC=bla,DC=bla` and supply the password (using ASN1/Bern over a TCP socket, etc). When I try `UPN=Admin@ourdomain.com` this fails. What's the correct way to utilize a UPN? Can it be done in the same way as bind with CN?

Comment: @tester778899 Just `Admin@ourdomain.com`. This is how it works from an Active Direcory point of view, I don't know how the LDAP library you are using works... but the UPN is meant to be used for authentication...

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work by simply not using `upn=` and also I had the domain wrong.